# How to remove Double Quotes from JSON array when there is no key value?

Tags: java, json

How do I create and pass an array without extra Double quotes. In below examples, I need to pass a value like this: ["XXXXXXX"]

```
        array.put(newUserId);
        log.info("array to string: "+array.toString();
```

Debug observations:

```
 JSONArray array = new JSONArray();  - is creating array like this - "[]"
        array.put(newUserId); "XXXXXXXX"
        log.info("array to string: "+array.toString();"["XXXXXXXX"]"
```

Comment: What is the issue exactly?

Comment: A [string in JSON](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-7) has double-quotes around it.  That does not mean the string’s content consists of double-quotes at the start and end.

Comment: 1 - You say debug observations, if you are using IntelliJ, try using a debug point and evaluating the value of your array. It should show ["XXXXXXXXX"]

Comment: 2 - You could also test that it is still an array by iterating over it. If it is an array this will work, if its a string it should fail.

Comment: yes That's what I did.  At the debug point, it was showing "["XXXXXXXX"]". In line 1, when array is declared, while debugging it is showing me like this "[]" . Even the Json array description showed it will have only square braces. Not sure where the double quotes are coming from

Answer (score 1):

I think you could possibly be having an issue with your logger, if the output is showing the array with double quotes on the outside of it

```
@Test
void foo()
{
    String newUserId = "A1B2C3D4";

    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    System.out.println("The empty array is: " + array);

    array.put(newUserId);
    System.out.println("The populated array is: " + array);
}
```

I created this little test function, added `org.json:json:20240303` to my test project, and ran it. When I use `System.out.println` to output the string, there are no quotes wrapping the outside of the array.

```
The empty array is: []
The populated array is: ["A1B2C3D4"]
```

Here is even a screenshot from my IDE to show the wrapping quotes aren't there.

[image: json-array-no-outer-quotes]

So, whatever is presenting you the via your logger is either adding the extra quotes because it's a string, or your logger is adding them. Most things that would add the outside wrapping quotes would also then "JSON Encode" the rest of the string, by adding backslashes before the inner double quotes. That would normally look something like: `"[\"A1B2C3D4\"]"`